# comparison of two files made on the basis of two columns in but retaining two duplicate lines with a pattern

Tags: unix, awk

file1:

```
scaffold2232_size19577   gene       8878    9258
scaffold2232_size19577   CDS        8878    9258
scaffold2232_size19577   gene       10631   14562
scaffold2232_size19577   intron     10693   11242
scaffold2232_size19577   intron     11343   14252
scaffold2232_size19577   intron     14346   14499
scaffold2232_size19577   CDS        10631   10692
scaffold2232_size19577   CDS        11243   11342
scaffold2232_size19577   CDS        14253   14345
scaffold2232_size19577   CDS        14500   14562
scaffold2232_size19577   gene       18807   19055
scaffold2232_size19577   CDS        18807   19055
```

file2:

```
scaffold2232_size19577   8878   9258    Os12t0508300-01
scaffold2232_size19577   8878   9258    Os12t0508300-01
scaffold2232_size19577   10631  14562   Os12t0508300-01
scaffold2232_size19577   10693  11242   Os12t0508300-01
scaffold2232_size19577   11343  14252   Os12t0508300-01
scaffold2232_size19577   14346  14499   Os12t0508400-00
scaffold2232_size19577   14346  14499   Os12t0508400-00
scaffold2232_size19577   14346  14499   Os12t0508400-00
scaffold2232_size19577   10631  10692   Os12t0508300-01
scaffold2232_size19577   11243  11342   Os12t0508300-01
scaffold2232_size19577   14253  14345   Os12t0508400-00
scaffold2232_size19577   14253  14345   Os12t0508400-00
scaffold2232_size19577   14253  14345   Os12t0508400-00
scaffold2232_size19577   14500  14562   Os12t0508400-00
scaffold2232_size19577   14500  14562   Os12t0508400-00
scaffold2232_size19577   14500  14562   Os12t0508400-00
scaffold2232_size19577   18807  19055   Os12t0508400-00
scaffold2232_size19577   18807  19055   Os12t0508400-00
scaffold2232_size19577   18807  19055   Os12t0508400-00
scaffold2232_size19577   18807  19055   Os12t0508400-00
scaffold2232_size19577   18807  19055   Os12t0508400-00
scaffold2232_size19577   18807  19055   Os12t0508400-00
```

desired output:

```
scaffold2232_size19577   8878   9258    Os12t0508300-01 gene
scaffold2232_size19577   8878   9258    Os12t0508300-01 CDS 
scaffold2232_size19577   10631  14562   Os12t0508300-01 gene
scaffold2232_size19577   10693  11242   Os12t0508300-01 intron
scaffold2232_size19577   11343  14252   Os12t0508300-01 intron
scaffold2232_size19577   14346  14499   Os12t0508400-00 intron
scaffold2232_size19577   10631  10692   Os12t0508300-01 CDS
scaffold2232_size19577   11243  11342   Os12t0508300-01 CDS
scaffold2232_size19577   14253  14345   Os12t0508400-00 CDS
scaffold2232_size19577   14500  14562   Os12t0508400-00 CDS
scaffold2232_size19577   18807  19055   Os12t0508400-00 gene
scaffold2232_size19577   18807  19055   Os12t0508400-00 CDS
```

i tried doing: `awk '{a[$1,$2,$3]=$0}END{for(i in a) print a[i]}' file2`

but with this i am loosing one of the gene/CDS line as they have same co-ordinates in col[2],[3]
so the output is coming:

```
scaffold2232_size19577    8878  9258    Os12t0508300-01 
scaffold2232_size19577   10631  14562   Os12t0508300-01 
scaffold2232_size19577   10693  11242   Os12t0508300-01
scaffold2232_size19577   11343  14252   Os12t0508300-01
scaffold2232_size19577   14346  14499   Os12t0508400-00
scaffold2232_size19577   10631  10692   Os12t0508300-01
scaffold2232_size19577   11243  11342   Os12t0508300-01
scaffold2232_size19577   14253  14345   Os12t0508400-00
scaffold2232_size19577   14500  14562   Os12t0508400-00
scaffold2232_size19577   18807  19055   Os12t0508400-00
```

i thought i can later add the col[2] of file1 to file2 but the number of rows are less after this operation of awk, so i am unable to add them.
i want this to be like my desired output.

Comment: is files `tab` seperated?

Comment: yes, it is tab separated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2FS$3]=$4;next} {print $1,$3,$4,a[$3FS$4],$2}' OFS="\t" f2 f1
scaffold2232_size19577  8878    9258    Os12t0508300-01 gene
scaffold2232_size19577  8878    9258    Os12t0508300-01 CDS
scaffold2232_size19577  10631   14562   Os12t0508300-01 gene
scaffold2232_size19577  10693   11242   Os12t0508300-01 intron
scaffold2232_size19577  11343   14252   Os12t0508300-01 intron
scaffold2232_size19577  14346   14499   Os12t0508400-00 intron
scaffold2232_size19577  10631   10692   Os12t0508300-01 CDS
scaffold2232_size19577  11243   11342   Os12t0508300-01 CDS
scaffold2232_size19577  14253   14345   Os12t0508400-00 CDS
scaffold2232_size19577  14500   14562   Os12t0508400-00 CDS
scaffold2232_size19577  18807   19055   Os12t0508400-00 gene
scaffold2232_size19577  18807   19055   Os12t0508400-00 CDS
```

Comment: You don't really need the `FS` while constructing the composite key. This would work just fine `awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2,$3]=$4;next} {print $1,$3,$4,a[$3,$4],$2}' OFS="\t" f2 f1` and looks cleaner too.

Comment: @jaypal I have burned my finger by not separating well, and found that  `FS` works well :)

Comment: @Jotne The `,` actually separates using `SUBSEP` which is a non-printing character which ensures safe separation of multiple keys. See [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multidimensional) for more details.

Comment: @jaypal Thanks for info.  I will look at this in next cross way :)